# Get some random and some specific records in a single query?

Tags: sql, mysql, random

So I have a cover-flow style image carousel populated by a query like

```
SELECT foo FROM `imageTable` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 12;
```

My client would like to add to this a set of permanent images.  Due to the way the results are used it would be very handy if I could make those records part of my original query.

I tried

```
SELECT foo FROM `imageTable` WHERE `id` = 'x' OR `id` = 'y' 
  OR `id` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 12;
```

I was hoping the records with the ids would necessarily be in the result set but nope the RAND() shuffles the whole set.

So my question is whether any single query could provide the x permanent records and then y random records?

// EDIT WITH REVISED QUERY USING Adrian Serafin's answer:

```
(SELECT * FROM `imageTable` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 6)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `imageTable`  WHERE `id` = 'foo' OR `id` = 'bar' OR `id` = 'baz')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try union command in sql.

```
select random
  union
select choosed
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  That works great!  Thanks for teaching me  new one!

Answer (score 1):

You might try a union...

`(SELECT foo FROM imageTable WHERE id not in ( 'x','y') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 12; )
UNION
(SELECT foo FROM imageTable WHERE id in ('x','y')
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;`

Comment: Thanks John!  I hadn't know about using in ('x','y') like that either so I learned tow new tricks.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Union them together, but prevent X and Y from showing more than once
You can also use IN instead of multiple OR statements to be more concise.

```
SELECT foo FROM (
    SELECT foo FROM `imageTable`
    WHERE id NOT IN ('x','y','z')
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 9    # reduce by 3
) A
UNION ALL
SELECT foo FROM (
    SELECT foo FROM `imageTable`
    WHERE id IN ('x','y','z')
) B
ORDER BY RAND()    # order again so that x,y,z are anywhere in the set
```

Comment: I was under the impression that simply using `UNION` *instead* of `UNION ALL` would eliminate duplicates from the results. Now, if that's true, I'm not sure whether that elimination happens before or after LIMIT 10 is applied to the random query, which might cause a problem...